# Pagination in SQL SELECT with ORDER BY based on CASE generated columns - TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, pagination, sql-order-by, case

I am using MS SQL SERVER 2008 and I have created the following query (simplified);

```
SELECT DATE_A, DATE_B
CASE
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A, GETDATE()) >= 1 THEN 1
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_B, GETDATE()) >= 1 AND DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A, GETDATE()) <1 THEN             2
ELSE 3
END AS sortPriority,
CASE
--deadline past
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A, GETDATE()) >= 1 THEN DATE_A
--review only past
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_B, GETDATE()) >= 1 AND DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A()) <1 DATE_B
--anything else
ELSE DATE_B
END AS sortDate
FROM myTable
WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A, GETDATE()) >=1 OR DATEDIFF(day, DATE_B, GETDATE()) >=1)
ORDER BY sortPriority, sortDate;
```

The query returns rows where DATE_A or DATE_B are older than todays date. The rows are sorted by sortPriority and then by sortDate.

I now need to add pagination to this query, however when I use the sortPriority or sortDate  columns in the order by clause of the ROW_NUMBER() function, the query fails;

```
WITH sortedTable AS
(
SELECT DATE_A, DATE_B,
CASE
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A, GETDATE()) >= 1 THEN 1
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_B, GETDATE()) >= 1 AND DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A, GETDATE()) <1 THEN 2
ELSE 3
END AS sortPriority,
CASE
--deadline past
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A, GETDATE()) >= 1 THEN DATE_A
--review only past
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_B, GETDATE()) >= 1 AND DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A()) <1 DATE_B
--anything else
ELSE DATE_B
END AS sortDate,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (sortPriority, sortDate) AS 'RowNumber'
FROM myTable
WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A, GETDATE()) >=1 OR DATEDIFF(day, DATE_B, GETDATE()) >=1)
)
SELECT * 
FROM sortedTable 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

I get the following error messages;

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Invalid column name 'sortPriority'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Invalid column name 'sortDate'.
```

And the line number refers to this line of my sample code;

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (sortPriority, sortDate) AS 'RowNumber'
```

How can I approach this and get the desired result (pagination with original sorting intact)

Comment: In what way does the query fail? Do you have an error message?

Comment: I am not sure if you can derive and use column (sortPriority, sortDate) in the same select statement .. sortPriority and sortDate are used in RowNumber

Comment: Hi Daniel - I have updated my question with the error details.

Comment: Thanks Nitin, that being the case how would you approach this query? I have relatively limited SQL experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNTESTED:

```
WITH sortedTable AS
(
    SELECT DATE_A, DATE_B, sortPriority, sortDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (sortPriority, sortDate) AS 'RowNumber'
      FROM
          (
            SELECT DATE_A, DATE_B,
                   CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A, GETDATE()) >= 1 THEN 1
                        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_B, GETDATE()) >= 1 AND DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A, GETDATE()) <1 THEN 2
                        ELSE 3
                    END AS sortPriority,
                   CASE
                        --deadline past
                        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A, GETDATE()) >= 1 THEN DATE_A
                        --review only past
                        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_B, GETDATE()) >= 1 AND DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A()) <1 DATE_B
                        --anything else
                        ELSE DATE_B
                    END AS sortDate
               FROM myTable
              WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, DATE_A, GETDATE()) >=1 OR DATEDIFF(day, DATE_B, GETDATE()) >=1)
          ) T
)
SELECT * 
FROM sortedTable 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```